# Can't import numpy just in .ipynb vscode page, but it works well in every other way

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I met a weird problem. I can `import numpy as np` successfully in IPython Shell, Python Scripts and Jupyter Notebook Webpage, but can't do that in jupyter notebook of vscode. **I ensured that these ways were using the same kernel as the filepaths are same too.**

- Working well in IPython Shell

```
(base) PS C:\Users\exp> conda activate DataAnalyse
(DataAnalyse) PS C:\Users\exp> ipython

Python 3.6.13 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 16 2021, 11:37:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.16.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]:
```

- Working well in Jupyter Notebook WebPage:
  [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbHp3.png)

```
In[1]: import sys
       print(sys.version)
       print(sys.executable)
Out[1]:3.6.13 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 16 2021, 11:37:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
       C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\DataAnalyse\python.exe
In[2]: import numpy as np
```

- **Not Working** in Vscode jupyter:[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ql4gF.png)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\DataAnalyse\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>
     21 try:
---> 22     from . import multiarray
        global multiarray = undefined
     23 except ImportError as exc:

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\DataAnalyse\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py in <module>
     11 
---> 12 from . import overrides
        global overrides = undefined
     13 from . import _multiarray_umath

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\DataAnalyse\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py in <module>
      6 
----> 7 from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
        global numpy.core._multiarray_umath = undefined
        global add_docstring = undefined
        global implement_array_function = undefined
        global _get_implementing_args = undefined
      8     add_docstring, implement_array_function, _get_implementing_args)

ImportError: DLL load failed: Can't find

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-0aa0b027fcb6> in <module>
----> 1 import numpy as np
        global numpy = undefined
        global np = undefined

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\DataAnalyse\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    138     from . import _distributor_init
    139 
--> 140     from . import core
        global core = undefined
    141     from .core import *
    142     from . import compat

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\DataAnalyse\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>
     46 """ % (sys.version_info[0], sys.version_info[1], sys.executable,
     47         __version__, exc)
---> 48     raise ImportError(msg)
        global ImportError = undefined
        global msg = '\n\nIMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!\n\nImporting the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for\nmany reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was\ninstalled.\n\nWe have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:\n\n    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html\n\nPlease note and check the following:\n\n  * The Python version is: Python3.6 from "C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\envs\\DataAnalyse\\python.exe"\n  * The NumPy version is: "1.19.2"\n\nand make sure that they are the versions you expect.\nPlease carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.\n\nOriginal error was: DLL load failed: Can't find module.\n'
     49 finally:
     50     for envkey in env_added:

ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.6 from "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\DataAnalyse\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.19.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed: Can't find specified module.
```

I have followed what the log says, but it redirect me into a Vscode official jupyter startup
tutorial, which seems to be nothing helpful.

Since the kernel is same, conda environment is same, I would ask how does this problem happen?

Comment: In your VSCode error log, Numpy connected with Miniconda package instead Anaconda. Please make sure you have linked VSCode to Anaconda. You can inspect this by running `!conda info` and `!conda list` to inspect your environment.

Comment: @lchsan Thanks for your tips. `!conda info` tells me that `active environment : None`, which isn't what I expected `active environment : DataAnalyse`, and that's the point. Appreciate your answer!